# ImmutableArray<> behaves differently than Array<> for nested Select with index

Tags: c#, linq, immutability, base-class-library

I am encountering what seems to be a very weird bug in `ImmutableArray<>` (with BCL Immutable collections v1.0.12.0, runtime .NET 4.5):

I have the following two identical structs exactly in the same source file under the same namespace:

```
public struct WeightedComponent {
    public readonly IComponent Component;
    public readonly decimal Weight;

    public WeightedComponent(IComponent component, decimal weight) {
        this.Component = component;
        this.Weight = weight;
    }
}

public struct WeightedComponent2 {
    public readonly IComponent Component;
    public readonly decimal Weight;

    public WeightedComponent2(IComponent component, decimal weight) {
        this.Component = component;
        this.Weight = weight;
    }
}
```

The following will throw an exception:

```
var elements1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(wc => new WeightedComponent(null, 0)).ToImmutableArray();
var foo = elements1.Select((e1, i1) => elements1.Select((e2, i2) => 0).ToArray()).ToArray();
if (foo.Length != 3) throw new Exception("Error: " + foo.Length); //Error: 1

var elements2 = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(wc => new WeightedComponent2(null, 0)).ToImmutableArray();
var foo2 = elements2.Select((e1, i1) => elements2.Select((e2, i2) => 0).ToArray()).ToArray();
if (foo2.Length != 3) throw new Exception("Error: " + foo.Length);
```

If I project elements1 into `ToArray()` on the first line instead of `ToImmutableArray()`, everything works fine.

The only difference between the two structs is that `WeightedComponent` is used extensively by the code before, while `WeightedComponent2` is never used before (this is why it may not be obvious to reproduce the bug).

Iterating on `elements1` twice in the same expression seem to be related to the issue, as if I remove it the `Select` works fine, but there is no such problem with `elements2`. 
It really seems to be related to the way the code behind `ImmutableArray<>` is considering both structs (maybe there is a caching mechanism?)

Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: ImmutableArray is brand new and beta quality so do expect problems.  Quacks like a GetHashCode problem.  If you don't get an answer and can't debug it then either send an email to Immo Landwerth or put a bounty on the question.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what is the best way to contact Immo? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/contact.aspx does not work...

Comment: His twitter handle is @terrajobst

Comment: Thanks I have sent him a tweet. Wow there is really a bug with Immutable collections vs. their mutable counterparts, I am now encountering another very wrong behavior that looks very similar in another place where I had replaced an array with an ImmutableArray: the first time I project an ImmutableArray of 3 elements to an ImmutableDictionary, I get 2 elements, and the second time I get 3 elements as expected...

Comment: As of version 1.0.34.0, there is no longer an `ImmutableArray<T>`. So this is definitely fixed :) [They plan it to bring it back](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time.aspx), so some good news there.

Comment: It is back in the version 1.1 beta though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the `ImmutableArray<T>` enumerator, triggered the first time you enumerate an empty instance of the collection. A future version of the NuGet package will have the issue fixed. In the meantime, I strongly suggest you avoid use of `ImmutableArray<T>`.